# How can I make labels with units and then position the label to the right of a bar?

Tags: labeling, plotting

I want to add units to my numbers to display them as the labels of my chart. I tried this:

```
sizes = {10718, 881, 395, 387, 375, 309, 297};
sizesStr = ToString[sizes] <> " kB";
BarChart[sizes, BarOrigin -> Left, ChartLabels -> Placed[sizesStr, Right]]
```

[image]

So instead of each bar displaying "xxx kB" I get the "kB" after the whole list. Should I blame `StringJoin` for not being listable? How do I get the numbers in each of the bars?

Related: for the short bars the text will go beyond the vertical axis. Can I get the labels at the right of the bars, instead of inside them?

Comment: Yes it was the non `Listable` aspect of `ToString` that brought you undone. I've taken the liberty of modifying the title to make it more reflective of the question

Answer (score 6):

This can be done in one of two ways. In both cases I am bypassing the creation of `sizesStr`:

```
sizes = {10718, 881, 395, 387, 375, 309, 297};
BarChart[sizes, BarOrigin -> Left, LabelingFunction -> (Placed[
     Row[{#1, " kB"}], {{1, 0.5}, {0, 0.5}}] &)]
```

[image]

For that example I am using `Row` to "join" the value with the unit. I am using the `Placed` syntax to be found at the bottom of Details in the docs.

[image]

Note that {*pos*, *epos*} are scaled coordinates therefore `{{1, 0.5}, {0, 0.5}}` means that I am placing the middle of the left edge of the label `{0,0.5}` at the middle of the right edge of the bar `{1,0.5}`. Adding a `Spacer` might make it more aesthetically pleasing: `Row[{Spacer[5], #1, " kB"}]`

Alternatively:

```
BarChart[sizes, BarOrigin -> Left, 
 ChartLabels -> 
  Placed[sizes, {{1, 0.5}, {0, 0.5}}, ToString[#] <> " kB" &]]
```

[image]

In this example the third argument to `Placed` is used, i.e. a function that converts the value to a string and joins " kB" to it.